# Music library for using with threads

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, audio

I would like to write programs that play music ( audio or midi or even pure tones will be ok)

But I would like to use it with threads, a thread play a sound while other thread play other sound.

- Threads 1 * Can play pure tones in different intensity and frecuency
  (to form a more complex envelop, creating the "timbre" of the sound))
- Threads 2 * A group of threads 1 could play different notes in a given timbre
  (to form chords from an instrument sound)
- Threads 3 * A group of threads 2 could play chords in different notes
         (to represent a musician)
- Threads 4 * A group of threads 3 can become an orchestra! =)

The hard part here I think is that I want to output different sounds at same time, preprocessing that would be the typical way, but if the mix of sound can be done live, it becomes really more interesting.

Any ideas, experiences, libraries or info would help, thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm hesitant to post this as an actual answer, but you might be able to glean an idea or two for how to implement @Tyler's answer from my related codegolf answer: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/272/twinkle-twinkle-little-star/395#395

Comment: Since you do not mention an specific OS, I would recommend taking a look at fmod (http://www.fmod.org/index.php/download).

Comment: @mootinator thank you for the reference, @yms.cu I will check it

Answer (score 5):

I don't think threads are what you want here. The synchronization would be too difficult. What you probably want to do (and what I did for a similar application years ago), was maintain a data structure of active notes (could be implemented with class instances, or closures, or whatever works), and for each sample, call each item in the structure, sum the output (I'd recommend using signed 16bit math at this point, so your values are in a range of -32767 to +32768). To mix just sum the various signals.

Something like the following:

```
#ts = A clock, in eg, seconds, passed in to your calls for generation purposes.
sample = sum([notefunc(ts) for notefunc in notes])
#Now convert the sample to whatever format needed for your media lib
#Update notes array
```

... and repeat that loop 44100 times/sec. Some sort of buffering would probably be needed. Actual realtime was tricky. Back when I was playing around with this stuff (~2000 on a 233mhz G3 Powerbook) I could get real time with one or two simple notes, but not more.

Comment: what language/libraries have you used for sound output?

Comment: It was some sort of MacAudio module. Keep in mine this was Python 1.5.2 under OS8.6, so not at all relevant to the modern situation. These days I'd probably be looking at something like OpenAL or SDL.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look at the [GStreamer framework](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/). It allows you model audiostreams as "pipelines" composed of elements. Parallel elements will be automatically processed in different threads. Elements can be kept in sync using "clocks".

Have a look at the [manual](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html). The first 10 chapters will give you a good overview of the possibilities. (And it reads quickly.)

Looking at the [list of plugin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html)s there seems to be some support for midi.

Answer (score 1):

[jMusic](http://jmusic.ci.qut.edu.au/) seems to have a comprehensive library. The [links](http://jmusic.ci.qut.edu.au/ReferencesLinks.html#links) page on their site has further resources too. 
*[n.b. I haven't used this in anger; I looked at it some years back and went for a commercial package instead...]*

hth, R

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting [blog](http://www.rossbencina.com/) that joins the music and software together. [This page](http://www.rossbencina.com/code/lockfree) of the blog is dedicated to threading and lock free algorithms in musical software and there is a list of libraries. Also [here](http://www.rossbencina.com/code) is another list that you will be interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Think about using Juce library ( http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce.php).

It's a C++ crossplatform library. 
It has many different features ( http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/jucefeatures.php) in addition to audio function:

1. Threads syncronization functions
2. Gui building and graphics features
3. Support for VST plugins
4. Midi support
5. Double licensed (GPL 2.0 or proprietary licenses) allow you to redistribute your work or write closed source applications.

A lot of professional audio application are written with this library, like MAX/MSP ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_%28software%29 )

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [JFugue](http://www.jfugue.org/).
I have used this library myself for programming music using multiple threads.

As an experiment, I have adapted an existing [Piano module](http://blogs.openwonderland.org/2010/07/26/xland-modules/) that is also using JFugue.